# Parsing full JSON into SQL

Tags: sql, json, delphi

I have the following JSON (only a couple of nodes for display purposes):

```
[
  {
    "CareNotes": [
      {
        "CareNoteID": "34289e11-6433-4020-9734-224eb8caa11a",
        "CareNoteExtendedID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "ADLName": "Mobility",
        "FlagsText": "",
        "Note": "Help with walking, used as four wheel walker, was content.",
        "AnswerType": 1,
        "Fragment": "Help with walking",
        "RemedialText": null,
        "Details": null,
        "ServiceUserID": "bc300962-3653-491a-9ba9-afab10964af4",
        "ServiceUser": "Betty Test",
        "ServiceUserLastName": "Test",
        "ServiceUserForeNames": "Betty",
        "ServiceUserDateofBirth": "19/03/1901",
        "ServiceUserLocation": 15,
        "WorkerID": "53e6c7b9-2c80-451e-ba8c-abfb309380ac",
        "Worker": "Beth Beth",
        "VoidedByWorker": null,
        "_supersedeStackID": null,
        "SupersededByWorker": null,
        "WorkerLastName": "Beth",
        "DisplayOnShiftHandover": 0,
        "WorkerInitials": "B.B.",
        "SliderData": "Walk",
        "SliderData2": "Not entered",
        "SliderIcons": [
          {
            "IconID": 1093,
            "CareNoteText": "was content"
          },
          {
            "IconID": 1156,
            "CareNoteText": "used as four wheel walker"
          }
        ],
        "DateDone": "2019-09-30T21:24:41.994+00:00",
        "DateDoneSU": "2019-09-30T21:24:41.994+00:00",
        "Duration": "9 minutes",
        "DurationInt": 9,
        "ActionIconID": 6001,
        "mraCareOrder": 5000,
        "wasPlanned": false,
        "qrVerified": false,
        "qrData": null,
        "nfcVerified": null,
        "inVerified": null,
        "ViaMonitor": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am not particularly good at SQL and have been frantically relearning what I did at uni and an old job 13yrs ago, in order to complete a project that takes JSON data from APIs of a care management solution, into my Delphi application that then processes the data to work out this and that. The JSON format is different depending on the report, and in the case of the CareNotesReport, the above JSON is what is produced.

My Delphi app pulls this JSON verbatim and dumps it to a .json file, with an ADO query that then executes the following code (along with some other select queries that are irrelevant here):

```
use CMUtility;


DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\CMU\Win32\Debug\carenotesreport.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

drop table if exists jsoncarenotes

select * into JSONCareNotes
from OPENJSON(@JSON,'$.CareNotes')
with (
    DateDone nvarchar(10) '$.DateDone',
    ServiceUser nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUser',
    ServiceUserLastName nvarchar(50) '$.ServiceUserLastName',
    SUDOB nvarchar(15) '$.ServiceUserDateofBirth',
    Note nvarchar(255) '$.Note',
    ADLName nvarchar(200) '$.ADLName',
    FlagsText nvarchar(255) '$.FlagsText',
    Fragment nvarchar(255) '$.Fragment',
    RemedialText nvarchar(255) '$.RemedialText',
    Worker nvarchar(30) '$.Worker',
    ServiceUserID nvarchar(100) '$.ServiceUserID',
    WorkerID nvarchar(100) '$.WorkerID',
    CareNoteID nvarchar(255) '$.CareNoteID',
    SID1 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[0].IconID',
    SText1 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[0].CareNoteText',
    SID2 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[1].IconID',
    SText2 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[1].CareNoteText',
    SID3 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[2].IconID',
    SText3 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[2].CareNoteText',
    SID4 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[3].IconID',
    SText4 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[3].CareNoteText',
    SID5 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[4].IconID',
    SText5 nvarchar(255) '$.SliderIcons[4].CareNoteText'
    )
    as CareNotes
```

I have a couple of issues. With the above code, I've had to strip the first [ and ] from the JSON file to get it to work, but due to the size of some returns I've had to change the use of a memorystream to a filestream within Delphi. This has created the problem in that although I can trim the last ] of the file, I am so far unable to find a reliable (and easy) method for trimming the first [. Therefore, I'm forced to conclude that it is my SQL code that is the weak link, and that it needs to be able to process the JSON with these two characters included.

Please can someone show me where I'm going wrong. I'm aware that the original JSON appears to be array, object, array, object, but I don't know where to go from that. Also, I've fudged the ability to read SliderIcons as I know there are a maximum of 5 objects of that array, but would prefer a more dynamic solution if possible.

Any assistance given in terms of either the way to remove that first [ in Delphi, or better SQL to handle the original JSON would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Ant

Comment: I've seemingly done the least-preferred option, which was to strip the [ and ] within Delphi. I copied the filestream to a second, and then used the Position and Size-1 method to strip them out. I'd still be interested in hearing about SQL methods, however.

Comment: The `[ .. ]` suggest it's an array value, with potentially multiple elements in it. The json parser should be able to handle that whole document, but then the root element will be an array of which you can take the first item to get the same effect that you have now.

Comment: Curious, though, why you are parsing JSon in SQL rather than Delphi, and how come these are so big that a memory steam is not enough. Do you have 1GB Json strings? Unfortunately there is no Delphi code in the question to give feedback on.

Comment: @GolezTrol the only element received from the JSON though is the detail provided in the example above. That is how it appears, and possibly it's just part of a series of information arrays, but the API only gives access to the CareNotes section. In answer to the question about Delphi, I did have delphi code that worked, but in the end I re-visited and decided I wanted a second, server-style app that handled all the scheduled pulldowns and stuck it into SQL, so I figured the best way to do it would be through SQL itself.

Comment: I did not have any issues using a memory stream until I started pulling in a month's worth of data across multiple homes. Even though I would 'free' the stream after each one, I think maybe it was the consolidated use that pushed it over? As I said in the OP, I'm no professional programmer and so I'm muddling through the best I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse this `JSON` input using SQL Server capabilities. If your `JSON` input has this fixed format (an array with one item and nested `JSON` arrays), you need an additional `APPLY` operator with `OPENJSON()` call to parse the nested `JSON` array. Note, that when the referenced property contains an inner `JSON` object or array you need to use the `AS JSON` option in the column definition.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

--SELECT @json = BulkColumn
--FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\CMU\Win32\Debug\carenotesreport.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j

SELECT @json = N'[
   {
      "CareNotes":[
         {
            "CareNoteID":"34289e11-6433-4020-9734-224eb8caa11a",
            "CareNoteExtendedID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "ADLName":"Mobility",
            "FlagsText":"",
            "Note":"Help with walking, used as four wheel walker, was content.",
            "AnswerType":1,
            "Fragment":"Help with walking",
            "RemedialText":null,
            "Details":null,
            "ServiceUserID":"bc300962-3653-491a-9ba9-afab10964af4",
            "ServiceUser":"Betty Test",
            "ServiceUserLastName":"Test",
            "ServiceUserForeNames":"Betty",
            "ServiceUserDateofBirth":"19/03/1901",
            "ServiceUserLocation":15,
            "WorkerID":"53e6c7b9-2c80-451e-ba8c-abfb309380ac",
            "Worker":"Beth Beth",
            "VoidedByWorker":null,
            "_supersedeStackID":null,
            "SupersededByWorker":null,
            "WorkerLastName":"Beth",
            "DisplayOnShiftHandover":0,
            "WorkerInitials":"B.B.",
            "SliderData":"Walk",
            "SliderData2":"Not entered",
            "SliderIcons":[
               {
                  "IconID":1093,
                  "CareNoteText":"was content"
               },
               {
                  "IconID":1156,
                  "CareNoteText":"used as four wheel walker"
               }
            ],
            "DateDone":"2019-09-30T21:24:41.994+00:00",
            "DateDoneSU":"2019-09-30T21:24:41.994+00:00",
            "Duration":"9 minutes",
            "DurationInt":9,
            "ActionIconID":6001,
            "mraCareOrder":5000,
            "wasPlanned":false,
            "qrVerified":false,
            "qrData":null,
            "nfcVerified":null,
            "inVerified":null,
            "ViaMonitor":null
         }
      ]
   }
]'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    j1.DateDone,
    j1.Note,
    j2.IconID,
    j2.CareNoteText
--INTO JSONCareNotes    
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].CareNotes') WITH (
    DateDone nvarchar(10) '$.DateDone',
    Note nvarchar(255) '$.Note',
    -- add additional columns definitons
    SliderIcons nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.SliderIcons) WITH (
   IconID int '$.IconID',
   CareNoteText nvarchar(100) '$.CareNoteText'
) j2
```

Result:

```
DateDone    Note                                                        IconID  CareNoteText
2019-09-30  Help with walking, used as four wheel walker, was content.  1093    was content
2019-09-30  Help with walking, used as four wheel walker, was content.  1156    used as four wheel walker
```

Notes (`JSON` basics):

- When you want to parse `JSON` string and get results as table, use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table-valued function, with default or explicit schema.
- Function [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) extracts an object or an array from a `JSON` string. If the value is not an object or an array, the result is `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict` mode.
- Function [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) extracts a scalar value from a `JSON` string. If the `path` points to not a scalar value, the result is `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict` mode

Notes (`Delphi` and `SQL Server`):

- You can organize your logic as a stored procedure, that has one parameter - the JSON text. In this situation, you'll send the `JSON` directly to the SQL Server and using `OPENROWSET()` won't be needed (`OPENJSON()` needs additional [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions)).
- Executing a stored procedure with `Delphi` is an easy task using `ADO` for example.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so very much. I will digest this and try to learn!

Comment: @Ant I'm glad this answer helped.