# My JSON routine is no longer giving me data. Why?

Tags: json, sql-server

I've posted a couple of times about JSON, SQL and Delphi. I'm still in the SQL phase, and now I've created .sql bits of code here and there, I'm now in the processing of creating bespoke SPs to then pass parameters through, in order to (try and) be more efficient. My JSON, by way of an example, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626510/parsing-full-json-into-sql/58650515?noredirect=1#comment103681585_58650515), but a brief snippet is again below. I have found that I have to remove the beginning [ and ending ] to get my code to work in the past, but I've learnt to live with this (and have cut them off for this example):

```
    {
    "CareNotes": [
      {
        "CareNoteID": "34289e11-6433-4020-9734-224eb8caa11a",
        "CareNoteExtendedID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "ADLName": "Mobility",
        "FlagsText": "",
        "Note": "Help with walking, used as four wheel walker, was content.",
        "AnswerType": 1,
        "Fragment": "Help with walking",
        "RemedialText": null,
        "Details": null,
        "ServiceUserID": "bc300962-3653-491a-9ba9-afab10964af4",
        "ServiceUser": "Betty Test",
        "ServiceUserLastName": "Test",
        "ServiceUserForeNames": "Betty",
        "ServiceUserDateofBirth": "19/03/1901",
        "ServiceUserLocation": 15,
        "WorkerID": "53e6c7b9-2c80-451e-ba8c-abfb309380ac",
        "Worker": "Beth Beth",
        "VoidedByWorker": null,
        "_supersedeStackID": null,
        "SupersededByWorker": null,
        "WorkerLastName": "Beth",
        "DisplayOnShiftHandover": 0,
        "WorkerInitials": "B.B.",
        "SliderData": "Walk",
        "SliderData2": "Not entered",
        "SliderIcons": [
          {
            "IconID": 1093,
            "CareNoteText": "was content"
          },
          {
            "IconID": 1156,
            "CareNoteText": "used as four wheel walker"
          }
        ],
        "DateDone": "2019-09-30T21:24:41.994+00:00",
        "DateDoneSU": "2019-09-30T21:24:41.994+00:00",
        "Duration": "9 minutes",
        "DurationInt": 9,
        "ActionIconID": 6001,
        "mraCareOrder": 5000,
        "wasPlanned": false,
        "qrVerified": false,
        "qrData": null,
        "nfcVerified": null,
        "inVerified": null,
        "ViaMonitor": null
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now, I have created the following SP, which runs, creates the table and populates fields, but no data is forthcoming. The command I've used is `exec sp_get_carenotes @home_name = 'NAME OF HOME>>`. I have not altered the structure that I can tell from that which was working previously, and so I am forced to conclude it has SOMETHING to do with the fact that I now have dynamic SQL in this SP because some of it is dependent on the passed parameters. I have tried PRINT(@SQL) and Print(@SQL1) and it all appears the same as what's in my .sql files.

```
USE [CMUtility]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Get_CareNotes]    Script Date: 02/12/2019 12:14:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- ================================================================================
-- Author:      Me
-- Create date: 02/12/2019
-- Description: SP to obtain JSON export from CM and place into relevant SQL table
-- ================================================================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Get_CareNotes] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @home_name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) -- set up the variable for JSON file to load into

    DECLARE @FILEPATH NVARCHAR(MAX) -- for determining the JSON BULKCOLUMN below, as SQL will not allow adding of @home_name directly...
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) -- dynamic code to load JSON data into @JSON
    DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX) -- dynamic code to load @JSON into [JSONCareNotes-HOME NAME]

    SET @FILEPATH = 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\CMUServer\Win32\Debug\CareNotesReport-'+@home_name+'.json'
    SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX); SELECT @JSON = BULKCOLUMN FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@FILEPATH+''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j'
    EXEC(@SQL)

    SET @SQL1 = 'DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX); '

    IF OBJECT_id('[JSONCareNotes-'+@home_name+']') IS NOT NULL --if already there

    BEGIN
        SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + 'INSERT INTO [JSONCareNotes-'+@home_name+'] SELECT *'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    --if not there
        SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + 'SELECT * INTO [JSONCareNotes-'+@home_name+'] '
    END

    set @SQL1 = @SQL1 + '
        FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, ''$.CareNotes'') 
        WITH
        (   CareNoteID nvarchar(50) ''$.CareNoteID'',
            ADLName nvarchar(100) ''$.ADLName'',
            FlagsText nvarchar(255) ''$.FlagsText'',
            Note nvarchar(max) ''$.Note'',
            AnswerType nvarchar(100) ''$.AnswerType'',
            Fragment nvarchar(255) ''$.Fragment'',
            RemedialText nvarchar(max) ''$.RemedialText'',
            Details nvarchar(max) ''$.Details'',
            ServiceUserID nvarchar(100) ''$.ServiceUserID'',
            ServiceUser nvarchar(75) ''$.ServiceUser'',
            ServiceUserForeNames nvarchar(75) ''$.ServiceUserForenames'',
            ServiceUserLastName nvarchar(30) ''$.ServiceUserLastName'',
            ServiceUserDateofBirth nvarchar(10) ''$.ServiceUserDateofBirth'',
            ServiceUserLocation nvarchar(2) ''$.ServiceUserLocation'',
            WorkerID nvarchar(100) ''$.WorkerID'',
            VoidedByWorker nvarchar(100) ''$.VoidedByWorker'',
            WorkerLastName nvarchar(100) ''$.WorkerLastName'',
            Worker nvarchar(100) ''$.Worker'',
            Firstname nvarchar(50) ''$.FirstName'',
            LastName nvarchar(50) ''$.LastName'',
            DateUpdated nvarchar(10) ''$.DateUpdated'',
            Score nvarchar(3) ''$.Score'',
            TypeName nvarchar(50) ''$.TypeName'',
            DisplayOnShiftHandover nvarchar(2) ''$.DisplayOnShiftHandover'',
            WorkerInitials nvarchar(10) ''$.WorkerInitials'',
            SliderData nvarchar(max) ''$.SliderData'',
            SliderData2 nvarchar(max) ''$.SliderData2'',
            DateDone nvarchar(10) ''$.DateDone'',
            Duration nvarchar(3) ''$.Duration'',
            ActionIconID nvarchar(10) ''$.ActionID'',
            wasPlanned nvarchar(6) ''$.wasPlanned'',
            qrVerified nvarchar(6) ''$.qrVerified'',
            nfcVerified nvarchar(6) ''$.nfcVerified'',
            inVerified nvarchar(6) ''$.inVerified'',
            ViaMonitor nvarchar(6) ''$.ViaMonitor'',
            SliderIcons nvarchar(max) as JSON   
        ) as j1

    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J1.SliderIcons) --but also load in any used SliderData information for this record
    WITH
    (
        IconID nvarchar(255) ''$.IconID'',
        CareNoteText nvarchar(max) ''$.CareNoteText''
    ) as J2'

    EXEC(@sql1)
END
```

Can anyone spot anything obviously wrong? TL:DR - My SP is supposed to create (or update, depending on whether or not the table exists already) a table, create columns from the JSON and then pass data into the table, using the passed parameters

Comment: **WARNING**: code like `'SELECT * INTO [JSONCareNotes-'+@home_name+'] '` is ***NOT*** injection safe. If you need to inject the names of objects, do so safely using `QUOTENAME`. Something like this: `N'SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(N'JSONCareNotes-'+@home_name)`

Comment: Yeah I did read up on some of that, but I figured before starting to change everything else, I'd at least get a version working lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @JSON variable in @SQL1 is null

```
SET @SQL1 = 'DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX); '
SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + 'INSERT INTO/SELECT [JSONCareNotes-'+@home_name+'] SELECT *'
set @SQL1 = @SQL1 + '
        FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, ''$.CareNotes'') .....
```

try this

```
DECLARE @MYJSON NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @JSON = BULKCOLUMN FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@FILEPATH+''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @JSON = @MYJSON OUTPUT;

.........

SET @SQL1 = 'INSERT INTO/SELECT [JSONCareNotes-'+@home_name+'] SELECT *'
SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + '
    FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, ''$.CareNotes'') .....'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL1, N'@JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)', @JSON = @MYJSON;
```

Comment: This is addressed via the `SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX); SELECT @JSON = BULKCOLUMN FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@FILEPATH+''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j'.`      ?

Comment: Thanks. I’ll give it a try!

Comment: I'm still puzzled though as to why `@JSON` is null. If I run the SP as a non-dynamic query it works fine. Is it something to do with the Exec command not having `@SQL`'s data and passing through to `@SQL1`, perhaps?

Comment: `each EXEC is a different execution level. user @variables are local to the execution level. if @variables transcended the execution level then the following would fail, because the same @variable is declared twice (not to mention the data type difference): declare @variable int; exec('declare @variable varchar(10)');`